# PPTP connection failures with client VPN

Tags: 14.04, networking, vpn, pptp, aws

I'm running trusty on AWS and am trying to connect to a client's VPN. They use Softlayer, whose [docs](http://knowledgelayer.softlayer.com/procedure/set-pptp-vpn-ubuntu) recommend connecting with PPTP. I've been able to connect successfully, but the connection is very flaky. The usual problem is that during a download it prints out messages like this in the syslog:

```
Sep  6 12:16:55 ip-10-81-174-94 pptp[60274]: anon warn[decaps_gre:pptp_gre.c:426]: discarding bogus packet 141074 (expecting 140756)
Sep  6 12:16:56 ip-10-81-174-94 pptp[60274]: anon warn[decaps_gre:pptp_gre.c:426]: discarding bogus packet 141075 (expecting 140756)
Sep  6 12:16:56 ip-10-81-174-94 pptp[60274]: anon warn[decaps_gre:pptp_gre.c:426]: discarding bogus packet 141076 (expecting 140756)
Sep  6 12:16:57 ip-10-81-174-94 pptp[60274]: anon warn[decaps_gre:pptp_gre.c:426]: discarding bogus packet 141077 (expecting 140756)
Sep  6 12:16:58 ip-10-81-174-94 pptp[60274]: anon warn[decaps_gre:pptp_gre.c:426]: discarding bogus packet 141078 (expecting 140756)
Sep  6 12:17:20 ip-10-81-174-94 pptp[60274]: anon warn[decaps_gre:pptp_gre.c:426]: discarding bogus packet 141079 (expecting 140756)
Sep  6 12:18:20 ip-10-81-174-94 pptp[60274]: anon warn[decaps_gre:pptp_gre.c:426]: discarding bogus packet 141080 (expecting 140756)
Sep  6 12:21:20 ip-10-81-174-94 pptp[60274]: anon warn[decaps_gre:pptp_gre.c:426]: discarding bogus packet 141081 (expecting 140756)
Sep  6 12:23:20 ip-10-81-174-94 pptp[60274]: anon warn[decaps_gre:pptp_gre.c:426]: discarding bogus packet 141082 (expecting 140756)
Sep  6 12:25:20 ip-10-81-174-94 pptp[60274]: anon warn[decaps_gre:pptp_gre.c:426]: discarding bogus packet 141083 (expecting 140756)
Sep  6 12:28:08 ip-10-81-174-94 pppd[60289]: Terminating on signal 15
Sep  6 12:28:08 ip-10-81-174-94 pptp[60288]: anon log[callmgr_main:pptp_callmgr.c:258]: Closing connection (shutdown)
Sep  6 12:28:08 ip-10-81-174-94 pptp[60288]: anon log[ctrlp_rep:pptp_ctrl.c:251]: Sent control packet type is 12 'Call-Clear-Request'
Sep  6 12:28:08 ip-10-81-174-94 pptp[60288]: anon log[call_callback:pptp_callmgr.c:79]: Closing connection (call state)
Sep  6 12:28:08 ip-10-81-174-94 pppd[60289]: Connect time 18.8 minutes.
Sep  6 12:28:08 ip-10-81-174-94 pppd[60289]: Sent 3135048 bytes, received 179722147 bytes.
Sep  6 12:28:08 ip-10-81-174-94 pppd[60289]: Script /etc/ppp/ip-down started (pid 65169)
Sep  6 12:28:08 ip-10-81-174-94 pppd[60289]: sent [LCP TermReq id=0x2 "User request"]
Sep  6 12:28:08 ip-10-81-174-94 pppd[60289]: Modem hangup
Sep  6 12:28:08 ip-10-81-174-94 pppd[60289]: Connection terminated.
```

The connection will then terminate and my code that pulls the data will hang forever. Other times, I run the same commands and it works fine. It seems like PPTP is very very old, and I'd be perfectly happy to replace it with something else, but it's pretty unclear to me if that's possible. Is there a better way to be doing this? Or something I'm missing here?